# It is possible to write concept requiring iteration over static tuple and checking each tuple item

Tags: c++, tuples, apply, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm writing simple code for automatic reflection of struct. in short each struct have static tuple with name and member pointer and code iterate over it using std::apply and do some stuff.

```
struct TestRecord{
    int id;
    long counter; 
};

template<>
struct RepositoryHelperID<TestRecord>
{
    static constexpr auto members = [] {
        return std::make_tuple(
            std::make_tuple("id"sv, &TestRecord::id),
            std::make_tuple("counter"sv, &TestRecord::counter));
    }();
};
```

it is working but i have some helper function (getDBType) for each type of member needed to whole code to work. to minimize compilation error size in case of missing this helper function i decided to create concept which should:

- iterate over static tuple
- get type of member from tuple element
- check if specific function exists for this type.

but i'm unable to make it work. if all function exist code compiles and it work. when function is missing i expect that concept is not fulfilled but instead i have compilation error about missing function.  i assumed if function is missing then require is not meet and concept fails, but as far i deduced template function needs to be evaluated to then check require statement. i try multiple combination of lambda function in std::apply but none worked.

i tried :

- lambda with require and empty body
- making simpler jump function with expected require on it.

below extracted full example of idea. and compiler explorer link https://godbolt.org/z/zss8aTM13

the question is if it is possible to make concept using tuples and std::apply.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#include <string_view>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

template <std::same_as<int> T>
std::string getDBType(){
    return "int";
}

template <std::same_as<double> T>
std::string getDBType(){
    return "double";
}

template<typename T>
struct RepositoryHelperID
{

};

struct TestRecord{
    int id;
    long counter; // change to double to compile 
};


template<>
struct RepositoryHelperID<TestRecord>
{
    static constexpr auto members = [] {
        return std::make_tuple(
            std::make_tuple("id"sv, &TestRecord::id),
            std::make_tuple("counter"sv, &TestRecord::counter));
    }();
};
template <typename T>
concept HaveGetType =
    requires {
        {
            getDBType<T>()
        };
    };



template <typename T>
concept RepositoryHelperConcept =
    requires(T) {
        {
            RepositoryHelperID<T>::members
        };
        {
            // std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().*std::get<1>(args))> == int , double etc. so check if eg. getDBType<int>() exists
              std::apply([](auto&&... args) {
                 ((getDBType<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().*std::get<1>(args))>>()), ...);
            },
                RepositoryHelperID<T>::members)
            
        };
    };

int main(){
    ///static_assert(!RepositoryHelperConcept<TestRecord>);
    return !RepositoryHelperConcept<TestRecord>;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::apply` is an unconstrained function, so the `requires`-clause will always trigger hard errors when the lambda passed in is ill-formed.

However, you can still use `std::apply` to check whether the return type of each member pointer after being invoked by the object satisfies `HaveGetType`

```
template <typename T>
concept HaveGetType = requires {
  getDBType<T>();
};

template <typename T>
concept RepositoryHelperConcept = requires {
  RepositoryHelperID<T>::members;
  requires std::apply([](auto&&... args) {
    return (
      HaveGetType<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().*std::get<1>(args))>
      > && ...);
  }, RepositoryHelperID<T>::members);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MfdM4M6ns)